# jQuery synchronous confirm dialog

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, event-handling, confirm

I use jQuery + Bootstrap + jqGrid plugin for handling grids.
When entering edit mode in a grid, one can tell this plugin either to exit the editing mode (and saving the changes) or to keep the edit mode (no savings).
Now the purpose is that this edit mode can only be closed by a confirm dialog.
Unfortunately this seems hard to implement since events are async...

Simple example (without confirmation):

```
//this works: either true or false wille be returned...
var saveRow = true;
//...
$grid.on("beforesaverow", function(){
    if (saveRow){
        return true; //OK: row will be saved ... exiting edit mode
    }
    else{
        return false; //NOT OK: row will not be saved ... continue edit mode
    }
});
```

The following situation does not work:

```
//this won't not work: true will always be returned!
var saveRow = true;
//...
$grid.on("beforesaverow", function(){
    confirmDialog("Save row?", function(answer){ //...open a simple bootstrap dialog with question yes/no...
        //...entering callback...
        if (answer){
            saveRow = true;
        }
        else{
            saveRow = false;
        }
    });
    return saveRow; //NOT OK: saveRow will always be "true"... function is ended but confirm is still busy...
});
```

And now how it should be implemented:

```
var saveRow = true;
//...
$grid.on("beforesaverow", function(){
    confirmDialog("Save row?", function(answer){ //...open a simple bootstrap dialog with question yes/no...
        //...entering callback...
        if (answer){
            saveRow = true;
            //obviously this is not correct because we are NOT returning "true" from "beforesaverow"...
            return true; //alternative needed...
        }
        else{
            saveRow = false;
        //obviously this is not correct because we are NOT returning "false" from "beforesaverow"...
        return false; //alternative needed...
        }
    });
});
```

This is only an example... I think this problem can occur anywhere using this construction...

What will work but is not good coding, is using plain old javascript:

```
$grid.on("beforesaverow", function(){
    var answer = window.confirm("Save row?"); //...open the browser's dialog with question ok/cancel...
    if (answer){
        saveRow = true;
    }
    else{
        saveRow = false;
    }
    return saveRow; //perfect! either true or false will be returned!
});
```

The browser's confirm dialog acts like an alert: program flow will be paused until the user closes the dialog... But this is not good practising...

@stackoverflow I already found something about deferred objects but this won't work too.
The problem seems to be that a child function should return his parent funtion I guess...

Another example to clarify that jqGrid is not really the issue:

```
$elem.on("click", function(e){
    var stopEventBubbling = false;
    confirmDialog("cancel this click event?", function(answer){
        stopEventBubbling = answer;
    }
    return stopEventBubbling; // the value of "stopEventBubbling" will never be the returned "answer" form the confirm dialog!
});
```

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used? and how you call the edit function?

Comment: Hi Tony, version 4.6.0. But jqGrid is not really the issue... my code here in the post is only some kind of pseudocode. i.e. you can replace the beforesaverow event to a click event : the problem remains the same...